# Error responses from api are considered success in react query

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-query

In React query every responses are considered as success.

Axios is used to call api request. Here is a axios component.

```
export const callAxios = async ({
    url,
    method,
    data,
    headers,
    params,
    responseType,
}: CallAxiosAPI) => {

    const config: AxiosRequestConfig = {
        method: method || 'GET',
        url: `${baseUrl}${url}`,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            Authorization: accessToken !== null ? `Bearer ${accessToken}` : '',
            ...headers,
        },
        data,
        params,
        responseType,
    }
    return axios(config)
        .then((res: AxiosResponse<any, any>) => {
            return res
        })
        .catch(err => {
            return err
        })
}
```

Here is sample of using useMutation

```
const adjustProfit = useMutation(
        ['adjustProfit'],
        (params: { configurationId: string; configurationPriceId: number; data: IAdjustType }) => {
            return PricingQueries.adjustProfit(
                parseFloat(String(params.configurationId)),
                params.configurationPriceId,
                params.data,
            )
        },
        {
            onSuccess: () => {
                refetch()
            },
            onError: () => {
                toast.error(t(`message.adjust_price_failed`))
            },
        },
    )
```

Even there is error onSuccess is called.

Comment: `axios` will throw by default if response's status code is not 2xx. Remove the `catch` block and let react-query handle the thrown error. Notice that you are returning the error instead of re-throwing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `.catch`. By catching an error because you want to log and then *not* re-throwing the error, you are transforming the error into a resolved Promise. So you're actually never returning the error to useQuery.

The fix is to remove the `catch` and use the `onError` callback for logging, or re-throw the error after logging.

This gotcha is so common that I have added it to my FAQ post:
https://tkdodo.eu/blog/react-query-fa-qs#why-do-i-not-get-errors-